# How to find max and min number from a file in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a list :

```
    a = 
[('N', '7289'), ('N', '7290'), ('N', '7291'), ('N', '7292'), ('N', '7293'), ('N', '7294'), ('N', '7295'), ('N', '7296'), ('N', '7297'), ('N', '7298'), ('N', '7299'),
 ('N', '7300'),('N', '7304'), ('N', '7305'), ('Z', '238.517'), ('N', '7306'),
 ('Z', '243.363'), ('N', '7307'), ('G', '0'), ('G','1'),('G','2')]
```

Here minimum for `N` is `7289`, for `Z` it is `238.517`, and so on...

So, I want these in my output means I want minimum and maximum from this list for all `N`, `Z` and `G` separately. I have no idea how to do it. For integers only the code is :

```
#> a = [(1,3),(2,5),(2,4),(7,5)]
#> zip(*a)
[(1, 2, 2, 7), (3, 5, 4, 5)]

#> map(max, zip(*a))
[7, 5] 

#> map(min,zip(*a))
[1, 3]
```

Comment: Do you want to compare strings or numbers?  Is `'2'` greater than or less than `'10'`?

Comment: comparing numbers for perticular character..like for N it is 7307 and for G it is 2 nd so on...

Comment: Then make sure to cast your string representations of numbers to a numeric type (`float` works here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution would be a bit simpler:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [('N', '7289'),
     #...
     ('G', '2')]

groups = defaultdict(list)
for tupl in a:
    key, value = tupl[0], float(tupl[1])
    groups[key].append(value)

for key, values in groups.iteritems():
    print key, max(values), min(values)
```

The output should be:

```
Z 243.363 238.517
G 2.0 0.0
N 7307.0 7289.0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

a = [('N', '7289'), ('N', '7290'), ('N', '7291'), ('N', '7292'), 
     ('N', '7293'), ('N', '7294'), ('N', '7295'), ('N', '7296'), 
     ('N', '7297'), ('N', '7298'), ('N', '7299'), ('N', '7300'), 
     ('N', '7304'), ('N', '7305'), ('Z', '238.517'), ('N', '7306'), 
     ('Z', '243.363'), ('N', '7307'), ('G', '0'), ('G','1'),('G','2')]

a.sort()
for k, g in groupby(a, key=itemgetter(0)):
    print(max(g, key=lambda x: float(x[1])))
```

Output:

```
('G', '2')
('N', '7307')
('Z', '243.363')
```

Comment: You can omit the `key` argument for `sorted`.  Also, the line continuation markings are superfluous.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski replaced `sorted` with call to `.sort`. You're right.

Comment: thanxx...got the output...and also got idea about itertools...!!

Comment: @user3519241:  Change `max(g)` to `max(map(float, g))` if you want the numeric maximum.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, @user3519241: won't work - `g` consists of `tuple`s. Edited.

Comment: what if there's a negative number..??

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

a = [('N', '7289'), ('N', '7290'), ('N', '7291'), ('N', '7292'), ('N', '7293'), ('N', '7294'), ('N', '7295'), ('N', '7296'), ('N', '7297'), ('N', '7298'), ('N', '7299'), ('N', '7300'),('N', '7304'), ('N', '7305'), ('Z', '238.517'), ('N', '7306'), ('Z', '243.363'), ('N', '7307'), ('G', '0'), ('G','1'),('G','2')]

a.sort(key=itemgetter(0,1))
for key, group in groupby(a, itemgetter(0)):
    print key, max([x[1] for x in group])
```

**Output：**

```
G 2
N 7307
Z 243.363
```